# How is ownership of generated files determined in Magento?

Tags: magento2, permissions

Since I started working with Magento 2 I have had consistent problems with permissions, usually with the `var/cache` directory. Typically when I clear cache using the command line I start running into problems (for example, errors accessing the cache sub dirs because it's owner/group is wrong).

**My question is, how is the user of generated files (such as cache) determined? What steps should be taken to prevent ever having permission issues?**

Comment: The files are usually generated by the logged in user. If you are logged in as root and execute a magento console command, the files generated should be owned by root also

Comment: More information can be found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: @tecjam The command I use includes $(whoami), so as you can probably guess I am logged in as the same user I want the permissions to apply to, and the same user I run cache:flush, setup:upgrade, etc., as.

Comment: @tecjam Actually I think this may have been working like you describe originally, but today I noticed everything is suddenly happening under php-fpm even though I'm of course not logged in as that

Comment: just make sure php-fpm and user you working with have write access to your files.....